# How to use head while iterating through a linked list?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, head

We are iterating through the linked list with the help of `head`, that is, we are updating our `head` as we move forward towards *i* th position. Please have a look at the fuction `insertIthnode`. I am inserting my `Node` at *i* th position are returning `head` - and it's still able to print the linked list. I don't know how? `head` is no longer pointing towards the first node then how is it still able to return a full linked list?

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
 public:
  int data;
  Node *next;

  Node(int data) {
    this->data = data;
    next = NULL;
  }
};

int length(Node *head) {
  int x = 0;
  Node *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    x += 1;
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  return x;
}

void printIthnode(Node *head, int i) {
  int n = length(head);
  if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) {
    cout << -1 << endl;
    return;
  }
  int count = 1;
  while (count <= i) {
    head = head->next;

    count++;
  }
  if (head) {
    cout << head->data << endl;

  } else {
    cout << "-1" << endl;
  }
}

Node *takeinput() {
  int data;
  cin >> data;
  Node *head = NULL;
  Node *tail = NULL;

  while (data != -1) {
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = n;
      tail = n;
    } else {
      tail->next = n;
      tail = n;
    }
    cin >> data;
  }
  return head;
}

void PrintLL(Node *head) {
  Node *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

Node *insertIthnode(Node *head, int i, int data) {
  if (i < 0) {
    return head;
  } else if (i == 0) {
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
    return head;
  }

  int count = 1;
  while (count <= i - 1 && head != NULL) {
    head = head->next;
    count++;
    if (count == i - 1) {
      Node *n = new Node(data);
      n->next = head->next;
      head->next = n;
      return head;
    }
    return head;
  }
}
int main() {
  /*Node n1(1);
  Node *head=&n1;
  Node n2(2);
  Node n3(3);
  Node n4(4);
  Node n5(5);
  Node n6(6);

  n1.next=&n2;
  n2.next=&n3;
  n3.next=&n4;
  n4.next=&n5;
  n5.next=&n6;
  */
  Node *head = takeinput();

  insertIthnode(head, 3, 7);
  PrintLL(head);
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you use the AddressSanitizer. Your code has issues. If you use `g++` or `clang++`, add these options when compiling: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`. Fix all the issues. Then also add `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`, then run the program to catch runtime issues.

Comment: There are multiple variables named `head` and that probably confuses you. In main call the head `main_head` and hopefully that makes it clearer that it has nothing to do with all the other `head` variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the main() function you are creating a head when you are taking input from the user with the help of the "takeInput()" function.

After that, you are calling the function "insertIthnode(head,3,7)" which is returning the head (since the return type is Node) but you are not receiving it in any variable so the head returned from the "insetIthnode" is lost.

Your original head remains the same as per of "takeInput()" function.

If you try to insert ith Node at Index 0 it won't print according to the inserted node.

Comment: Or try `Node *new_head = insertIthnode(head,3,7); PrintLL(new_head);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you consider the Node as the linked list. While this is valid, the whole point of the linked list is that you don't lose track of the head. You could use two approaches:

1. Don't iterate over the head. Instead, use a temporary reference to the head.
2. Implement a Linked List wrapper. You can keep a constant reference to the head while performing operations over the node.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `head` *by value*. Any changes you do to the variable receiving the value of `head` inside the functions are made to the local variable inside the function only and will not be visible from the call site.

Take your `PrintLL` function as an example:

```cpp
void PrintLL(Node *head) { // head is here a local variable 
  Node *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```

This could be rewritten without the extra variable `temp`. The name `head` doesn't make it the same `head` you used to call the function with:

```cpp
void PrintLL(Node* head) {
  while (head != nullptr) {
    cout << head->data << ' ';
    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

and it would not affect the `head` you passed in as a parameter.

Similarly:

```cpp
void foo(int x) {
    ++x;
    //
}

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    foo(x);
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // prints 10
}
```

Comment: thanks ted for  for the wonderful explanation!